# CollectionViewGroup.Items not raising PropertyChanged after having an item added?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid

I am trying to add grouping with subtotal sum into DataGrid. Read several articles: the solution is to have an `ObservableCollection` with the data, wrap it into `CollectionViewSource` which in turn will be `ItemsSource` for the DataGrid. Subtotal is calculated with a converter, which receives `Items` of `CollectionViewGroup` as input and calculates the sum.

All works fine only at the initial population of the `ObservableCollection`, or when adding an item creates the new group. But if an item is added into any existing group, converter is simply not called for recalculation - apparently `CollectionViewGroup.Items` is not raising `PropertyChanged` event?
I browsed a bit in [CollectionViewGroup source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Data/CollectionViewGroup.cs.html) - `Items` are `ReadOnlyObservableCollection<object>`, which should trigger `PropertyChanged` after an item added, shouldn't it?

Then I noticed, that `CollectionViewGroup.ItemCount` is displayed properly after adding new items, so I tried a trick with a `MultiBinding` - added a `IMultiValueConverter` converter which takes both `Items` and `ItemCount` as parameters, expecting `ItemCount` to trigger the recalculation. It worked, but again without full success - somehow the converter gets the correct input only once, when the new group is created. If an item was added to an existing group, `ItemCount` is correct, but `Items` are not! `Items` collection is missing the newly added item! 
E.g. when `ItemCount`=2, `Items` have only 1 "old" item (`Items.Count`=1). When `ItemCount`=3, `Items` have only 2 "old" items (`Items.Count`=2), etc. So again the converter cannot calculate the correct subtotal, because the input is incomplete...

It looks like the only working solution would be to call `Refresh()` for the whole `CollectionViewSource`, but that expands all the groups, cause flickering, breaks MVVM concept, so it is ugly...

So my questions are:

- Is there still any change to make `CollectionViewGroup.Items` raise `PropertyChanged` properly?
- Isn't it a bug in `CollectionViewGroup`, that Multi Converter receives `Items.Count` = `ItemCount` - 1?

Any advice would be highly appreciated!

The full sample code is on [GitHub](https://github.com/pavka1799/ObservableVsConverter.git)

Some code excerpts are below -
**XAML**:

```
            <DataGrid.GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,5"/>
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">                                       
                                    <Expander IsExpanded="True" BorderThickness="1,1,1,5">
                                        <Expander.Header>
                                            <DockPanel>
                                                <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding Path=Name}" Margin="5,0,0,0" Width="100"/>
                                                <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding Path=ItemCount}"/>
                                                <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="Sum 1: " Margin="5,0,0,0"/>
                                                <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold"  >
                                                    <TextBlock.Text>
                                                        <Binding Path="Items" Converter="{StaticResource sumConverter}" ConverterParameter="AmountValue" StringFormat="{}{0:N2}"/>
                                                    </TextBlock.Text>
                                                </TextBlock>
                                                <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="Sum 2: " Margin="5,0,0,0"/>
                                                <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold"  >
                                                    <TextBlock.Text>
                                                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource sumMulConverter}" ConverterParameter="AmountValue" StringFormat="{}{0:N2}">
                                                            <Binding Path="Items"/>
                                                            <Binding Path="ItemCount"/>
                                                        </MultiBinding>
                                                    </TextBlock.Text>
                                                </TextBlock>
                                            </DockPanel>
                                        </Expander.Header>
                                        <Expander.Content>
                                            <ItemsPresenter />
                                        </Expander.Content>
                                    </Expander>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
            </GroupStyle>
        </DataGrid.GroupStyle>
```

**Converters**:

```
    public class SumConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == DependencyProperty.UnsetValue) return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
        if (null == parameter) return null;
        string propertyName = (string)parameter;
        if (!(value is ReadOnlyObservableCollection<object>)) return null;
        ReadOnlyObservableCollection<object> collection = (ReadOnlyObservableCollection<object>)value;
        decimal sum = 0;
        foreach (object o in collection)
        {
            sum += (decimal)o.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).GetValue(o);
        }
        return sum;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class SumMulConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (null == parameter) return null;
        if (!(parameter is string)) return null;
        string propertyName = (string)parameter;

        if (values == DependencyProperty.UnsetValue) return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
        if (values == null) return null;
        if (values.Length < 2) return null;
        if (!(values[0] is ReadOnlyObservableCollection<object>)) return null;
        ReadOnlyObservableCollection<object> collection = (ReadOnlyObservableCollection<object>)values[0];
        if (!(values[1] is int)) return null;
        Debug.Print($"ItemCount={(int)values[1]}; Collection Count = {collection.Count}");
        decimal sum = 0;
        foreach (object o in collection)
        {
            sum += (decimal)o.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).GetValue(o);
        }
        return sum; //.ToString("N2", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Adding an item to a collection never raises a `PropertyChanged` event (this is because the property `CollectionViewGroup.Items` still has the same value, the same collection instance). Instead subscribe to the [`CollectionViewGroup.Items.CollectionChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.readonlyobservablecollection-1.collectionchanged?view=netframework-4.8) event. This event is raised every time an item was added/removed to/from the collection.

Comment: Thank you for the hint, @BionicCode! I shall try it.

Comment: Hmm... All suggestions I could find on subscribing to `CollectionChanged` are using code-behind. In this case, when it needs to be inside `<DataGrid.GroupStyle>`, I cannot see how to subscribe... @BionicCode - maybe you can further advise on this detail as well? Thank you!

Comment: Alright. Can you please tell me the type of the items inside the `DataGrid`? It has a property `AmountValue`, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to sum up the values in the view, a simple solution would be to create an Attached Behavior.

Also make use of LINQ: instead of using reflection you can cast the collection from object to the explicit type using `Enumerable.Cast<T>` or `Enumerable.OfType<T>`. To compute a sum of a collection based on an item's property, use `Enumerable.Sum`:

**GroupItemSumBehavior.cs**

```
public class GroupItemSumBehavior : DependencyObject
{
  #region IsEnabled attached property

  public static readonly DependencyProperty IsEnabledProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
    "IsEnabled", typeof(bool), typeof(GroupItemSumBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(default(bool), OnIsEnabledChanged));

  public static void SetIsEnabled(DependencyObject attachingElement, bool value) => attachingElement.SetValue(GroupItemSumBehavior.IsEnabledProperty, value);

  public static bool GetIsEnabled(DependencyObject attachingElement) => (bool) attachingElement.GetValue(GroupItemSumBehavior.IsEnabledProperty);

  #endregion

  #region Sum attached property

  public static readonly DependencyProperty SumProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
    "Sum", typeof(decimal), typeof(GroupItemSumBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(default(decimal)));

  public static void SetSum(DependencyObject attachingElement, decimal value) => attachingElement.SetValue(GroupItemSumBehavior.SumProperty, value);

  public static decimal GetSum(DependencyObject attachingElement) => (decimal) attachingElement.GetValue(GroupItemSumBehavior.SumProperty);

  #endregion

  private static Dictionary<IEnumerable, GroupItem> CollectionToGroupItemMap { get; set; }

  static GroupItemSumBehavior() => GroupItemSumBehavior.CollectionToGroupItemMap =
    new Dictionary<IEnumerable, GroupItem>();

  private static void OnIsEnabledChanged(DependencyObject attachingElement, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
  {
    if (!(attachingElement is GroupItem groupItem))
    {
      return;
    }

    var collectionViewGroup = groupItem.DataContext as CollectionViewGroup;
    bool isEnabled = (bool) e.NewValue;

    if (isEnabled)
    {
      CollectionToGroupItemMap.Add(collectionViewGroup.Items, groupItem);
      (collectionViewGroup.Items as INotifyCollectionChanged).CollectionChanged += CalculateSumOnCollectionChanged;
      CalculateSum(collectionViewGroup.Items);
    }
    else
    {
      CollectionToGroupItemMap.Remove(collectionViewGroup.Items);
      (collectionViewGroup.Items as INotifyCollectionChanged).CollectionChanged -= CalculateSumOnCollectionChanged;
    }
  }

  private static void CalculateSum(IEnumerable collection)
  {
    if (GroupItemSumBehavior.CollectionToGroupItemMap.TryGetValue(collection, out GroupItem groupItem))
    {
      decimal sum = collection
        .OfType<LineItem>()
        .Sum(lineItem => lineItem.AmountValue);

      SetSum(groupItem, sum);
    }
  }

  private static void CalculateSumOnCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e) 
    => CalculateSum(sender as IEnumerable);
}
```

**DataGrid GroupStyle**

```
<DataGrid.GroupStyle>
  <GroupStyle>
    <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">

        <Setter Property="GroupItemSumBehavior.IsEnabled" Value="True" />

        <Setter Property="Template">
          <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
              <Expander IsExpanded="True" BorderThickness="1,1,1,5">
                <Expander.Header>
                  <DockPanel>
                    <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding Path=Name}" Margin="5,0,0,0" Width="100" />
                    <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding Path=ItemCount}" />
                    <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="Sum: " Margin="5,0,0,0" />

                    <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold"
                               Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=(GroupItemSumBehavior.Sum)}" />
                  </DockPanel>
                </Expander.Header>
                <Expander.Content>
                  <ItemsPresenter />
                </Expander.Content>
              </Expander>
            </ControlTemplate>
          </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
      </Style>
    </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
  </GroupStyle>
</DataGrid.GroupStyle>
```